# finding the power of 2 of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, numbers

What is the most optimized way to find the power of 2 of a number. For example : if number is 64 then I want 6 as result.

P.S. : I have read many posts about how to check if the number can be represented as a power of 2 or not but they don't give the actual power as result.

Comment: You mean log (base 2) of a number ?

Comment: "the most optimized way" Not sure you really need the most optimized way. Usually I would advice to use the logarithm.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two [logarithm of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is the power it'd have to have to be that number:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log2(64)
6.0
```

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of hack. Convert it to binary number. If input is going to be a multiple of 2, then this would not be a problem

```
>> bin(2).count('0') -1
1
>>> bin(64).count('0') -1
6
>>> bin(1024).count('0') -1
10
>>> bin(1024)
'0b10000000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compute the logarithm of the number **in base 2**. Following are the two ways to do so

**Method 1**

```
import numpy as np

number = 64

power = np.log2(64)
# 6.0
```

**Method 2**

```
import math

math.log2(number)
# 6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an option (you are looking for the `log`arithm in base 2):

```
from math import log2


def integer_log2(n):
    if not bin(n).count("1") == 1:
        raise ValueError
    return int(log2(n))
```

in binary representation (`bin(n)`) a number an only be an integer power o 2 it it contains exactly one `1`. the function presented here will raise a `ValueError` if this is not the case.

```
integer_log2(64))
# 6
```

as you'd need the binary representation anyway, you could then also just count the number of `0`s to get the log:

```
def integer_log2(n):
    b = bin(n)
    if not b.count("1") == 1:
        raise ValueError
    return b.count("0") - 1
```